# SELF DESTRUCT and ReInit

Tags: contract-development, selfdestruct

Please, be kind, why some persons uses self destroy?
Why are the addresses of the contract not changed when removed?

Why is it  initiate by a third-party contract?

What does Contract ReInit mean for main contract in https://bscscan.com?

thank you